# How to send regular in-line SQL in entity framework

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

Now don't go getting all huffy just yet. This is only for a very specific situation. So rather than asking why I would EVER want to send in-line string SQL through EF, let's just try to stay on the topic of "how".

Do I need to do it the old-fashioned route using regular old ADO.NET or does EF provide me with a way to execute a straight sql select/nonquery?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you investigated [Entity SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387145.aspx)?

[Entity Framework Q&A](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc507640.aspx):

```
string city = "London";
using (Entities entities = new Entities()) 
{
  ObjectQuery<Customers> query = entities.CreateQuery<Customers>(
    "SELECT VALUE c FROM Customers AS c WHERE c.Address.City = @city",
    new ObjectParameter("city", city)
  );

  foreach (Customers c in query)
    Console.WriteLine(c.CompanyName);
}
```

Since Entity SQL currently lacks any
DML constructs, it is not possible to
issue Insert, Update, or Delete
commands using Entity SQL and Object
Services

Comment: Yes, entity sql is not what I need though I am aware of it. I am using LINQ 99.9% of the time, this is for one specific instance. It looks like I'll just have to set up a quick ADO.NET interface. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: I would say just let ADO.NET do it. I had a situation recently, similar to what you're asking, and found it to be easier and cleaner to just let plain old ADO.NET do the work real quick and dispose of it. Just my suggestion

Comment: Careful if you're using SqlQuery<> instead of ObjectQuery<> that your ObjectParameters become SqlParameters

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to *ObjectQuery* if you need more options to cross over multiple database tables, make use of `context.Database.SqlQuery<>` and `SqlParameter`.

Example:

```
var searchId = new Guid("16144A52-A092-4876-9C55-A0AD0109F08A");

var sqlparam = new SqlParameter("sid", searchId);

using (var context = new Entities())
{
    var sql = @"SELECT t1.Name, t2.ChildName
        FROM dbo.Table1 as t1 
        INNER JOIN dbo.Table1 as t2 
            ON t1.Id = t2.ParentId 
        WHERE t1.Id = @sid"

    var result = context.Database.SqlQuery<Combined>(sql, sqlparam);

    foreach(var r in result)
    {
         Console.WriteLine(r.Name + r.ChildName)
    }
}


public class Combined
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ChildName { get; set; }
}
```